# Marcar as checkbox criadas dinamicamente em caso de uma condição ser verdadeira

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá!
Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver. Quero "checkar" as checkbox que são geradas dinamicamente em meu código HTML. A estrutura funciona assim:

**1.** *A page é carregada;*
 **2.** *Ao clicar em um determinado botão, uma modal dinâmica é gerada;*
 **3.** *Todos os checkbox contidos nessa modal possuem a mesma classe ('**.checkbox**');*

Agora eis o problema! Preciso deixar a propriedade checked de cada checkbox como *true* caso satisfaça uma condição que irei fazer. Mas não consigo detectar essa checkbox e inserir essas alterações. Já utilizei o método on() e mesmo assim não consigo manipular essas checkbox.

Como posso realizar isso com JQuery?

Comment: Você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer desta forma, adicionando `true` a todos os `checkbox` com a classe `.checkbox`:

```js
$('#elemento').on('click', function(){
   if(1 == 1){ // condição
      $('.checkbox').prop('checked', true);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />


<input type="button" id="elemento" value="Checar tudo" />
```